# Datetime SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Tengo un aplicación que va generando registros y uno de los campos de la tabla de la bbdd es un Datetime con el siguiente formato: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Cuando hago una búsqueda en el SSMS si pongo por ejemplo:

```
select  Fecha, Unidades from RegistroUnidades where Fecha>='2023-03-20 13:01:15'and Fecha<='2023-03-20 13:31:15' order by TimeString desc
```

Me aparece error por convertir varchar a datetime, esto pasa porque en el SQL el diría que el formato de fecha es el siguiente: YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS

Se solucionarlo a través de código, pero me gustaría cambiar el formato del SQL.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Seguro que el tipo de dato de la columna `Fecha` es `DATETIME`? ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta el mensaje de error exacto que estás recibiendo? Es raro que el error hable de una conversión, si el tipo de dato fuese realmente `DATETIME` no debería ocurrir tal conversión. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta agregando más detalles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las columnas datetime, **no tienen ningún formato.** Se almacenan en binario.

```
Declare @miFecha datetime = '20230320 17:03:01'
Select @miFecha 

SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @miFecha);
```

[image: Res1]

De los 8 bytes que conlleva un valor datetime, 4 para la fecha y 4 para la hora. Me voy a quedar solo con los 4 de la izquierda, para extraer la fecha, que como se puede ver por la última select, es un varbinary.

```
DECLARE @miFecha DATETIME = '20230320 17:03:01'
SELECT SUBSTRING(
        CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), @miFecha)
        , 1
        , 4
        ) as miFecha;
```

[image: Res2]

Si se convierte ese binary en un int.

```
DECLARE @binaryToInt VARBINARY(8); 
SET @binaryToInt = 0x0000AFCB;
SELECT CONVERT(INT,@binaryToInt)
```

[image: Res3]

Ahora con ese número le aplicamos una función de fecha, sumándole los días que tiene el mismo, a la fecha establecida como punto de partida.

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,45003,'19000101')
```

[image: Res4]

.....

Pero eso no quita para que nosotros desde cliente, usamos un formato. Para esto, tanto el lenguaje de desarrollo como el management Studio usan un login, y es el login, el que determina que formato de la fecha viene dado por nuestro lenguaje por defecto.

[image: Res5]

Ahora creo una tabla de ejemplo

```
Create table fecha (fecha datetime)
Insert into fecha (fecha)
values
(getdate());
```

Y recupero los datos, poniendo un formato.

```
Select * from fecha 
where  Fecha>='2023-03-20 13:01:15'
and Fecha<='2023-03-20 17:31:15'
```

[image: res7]

Pero ahora a la misma base de datos, me conecto con un login en otro idioma.

[image: UserLoginSpanish]

Y la misma consulta que tengo en la otra ventana para el login, me da el error de conversión.

[image: Res8]

Si quiero, a la query, le puedo anteponer el formato en el que voy a recuperar los datos, y entonces funciona correctamente.

[image: res9]

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos! Me fui muy útil tu respuesta, cambie el idioma y ya iba todo correctamente muchas gracias! Solo por curiosidad, el `set dateformat ymd` si lo ejecuto se queda permanente en la configuración de SQL Server o una vez se reinicia vuelve al estado inicial?

Comment: No, es por consulta. Eso lo podrías anteponer a cualquier query, para fijar el comportamiento de la misma.

Comment: Técnicamente es por conexión. Se pueden ejecutar múltiples consultas dentro de la misma conexión, pero realmente no es la mejor opción.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que ni en la aplicación ni en la base de datos debes de basarte en los formatos. Internamente, cada sistema guarda la fecha como un valor numérico (o varios). Este valor, se puede representar de diversas formas según la configuración de la aplicación (la que desarrollas o la que usas como Management Studio).

Para evitar eso, tienes 2 opciones:

1. Utilizar siempre los valores fecha/hora en variables o atributos con el tipo correcto y no utilizar cadenas de texto.
2. Utilizar los formatos que no dependen de la configuración local. Estos formatos son `YYYYMMDD`, `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss.ms` o `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.ms`. En el último, la T es literalmente ese caracter en vez del espacio. Ejemplo:

```
SET DATEFORMAT YDM;

SELECT TRY_CAST( '20230320 13:01:15' as datetime),
       TRY_CAST( '2023-03-20T13:01:15' as datetime),
       TRY_CAST( '2023-03-20 13:01:15' as datetime);
```

Puedes combinar ambas soluciones, pero dale prioridad a la primera.

Un último punto, que puede ser más complicado, es que puedes cambiar la configuración de SQL Server para que tenga las configuraciones regionales correctas por default.